# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, fatal-error

Building the ToDo app. The app crashes when the new todo task is created.

The breakpoint stops the code and returns:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
 @IBAction func doneButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let title = textView.text, !title.isEmpty else {
        return
    }

    let todo = Todo(context: managedContext)
    todo.title = title
    todo.priority = Int16(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    todo.date = Date()

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        dismiss(animated: true)
        textView.resignFirstResponder()

    } catch {
        print("Error saving todo: \(error)")

    }

}
@IBAction func cancelButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
    textView.resignFirstResponder() 
}
```

Any ideas what could have caused the app crash? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: How do you declare `textView`? And the `segmentedControl`? If those are IBOutlets, make sure they're hooked up properly in the storyboard.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth  IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

Comment: This is common error found for beginners .Search it in google you find Thousands of answer

Comment: Are they connected with the storyboard properly?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth yeah. Connected properly     IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControlSegment!

Answer (score 1):

`UISegmentedControlSegment` is the public enum and `UISegmentedControl` is the `UIControl`
As per your comment, it seems that you have mistaken UISegmentedControl for UISegmentedControlSegment, so connect UISegmentedControl like below:

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
```

Comment: Thank you! But I have already fixed it myself and the app still doesn't work

Comment: Good catch! @Mansi